# jQuery - Dialog auto-resize on dynamic content and maintain center position

Tags: jquery, dialog, position, center

I have a jQuery Dialog box and Am loading the content using Ajax.

The Dialog is initially in the center of the page. The problem , here is , Since its a dynamic content, the size of the data is unknown. So, When I get large data, the dialog grows only in the bottom side i.e. The dialog expands in the bottom, and the top is still in the same position.

What I want is

When the data is loaded, the dialog should expand in both the direction (top and bottom ), so that the content is visible without scrolling.

Comment: Try calling "$( "#dialog" ).dialog({});" again after each ajax update?

Comment: @madhairsilence : If you found my answer good, please consider making it as "accepted". That will make it more visible for future visitors. Thanks!

Comment: The question already has an answer marked

Comment: @madhairsilence Isn't possible to untick the accepted answer and select a new one? As for myself, I'm able to do it in the question I've asked almost two years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default dialog is absolutely relative positioned.

The dialog may expand on giving **auto height**, but when the page is scrolled , the dialog is reposition itself.

The only way to do this is, apply these styles to the dialog

1. Position the dialog in the Window by

   `position : ['center',<distance from top>]`
2. Fix the position by using css style

   `.fixed-dialog { position:"fixed" }`
3. Add this class to the dialog

   `dialogClass : 'fixed-dialog'`

So, the dialog would look like

```
$('#dialog-div').dialog({
        position : ['center',10],
        dialogClass: "fixed-dialog"
    });
```

Answer (score 14):

None of the answers I found on the internet satisfied me while I was looking at the solution. Even this one doesn't. After reading a lot more about the JQuery API documentation, [I found something really interesting](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/). As this web page describe, you can bind an event in which it will be executed after the ajax request has done its job. Thing is, it's not simple as this; As I was doing my own tests, using the example provided in the API documentation, I couldn't make it to work. It seems like my JQuery dialog didn't exist in a "future" context manner.

This led me to [this page](http://api.jquery.com/live/) which description was: 
*Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.* Finding this leads me to create a function like this one:

```
$(document).live("ajaxStop", function (e) {
      $(".myDiagDiv").dialog("option", "position", "center");
});
```

And voila! It works like a charm! After the ajax request is done, the position property is changed and adapted to the content of the div and its dimensions!

Hope it helps people in the future!

EDIT: You might want to use the function ".on()" instead of ".live()". Since the time I wrote my answer, it seems like the function ".live()" as been removed in version 1.9 of jQuery and replaced by the new one. A more appropriate solution for users of jQuery >= 1.9 would be something like this:

```
$(document).on("ajaxStop", function (e) {
      $(".myDiagDiv").dialog("option", "position", "center");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Use this
    modal: true,
    width: '80%',
    autoResize:true,
    resizable: true,
    position: {
        my: "center top", 
        at: "center top", 
        of: window
    }
```

order must be same

Comment: What's `autoResize`? Can you reference the documentation?

Comment: autoresize is  an inbuilt  property which u can you for your modal window and it is of boolean type.

Comment: I don't see it in the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/). Can you direct me to it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use that function:

```
function centerDialog(id){

  var d = $('#'+id).closest('.ui-dialog'),
      w = $(window);

  d.css({

    'top':(w.height()-d.outerHeight())/2,
    'left':(w.width()-d.outerWidth())/2

  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Positioning was fine before I moved dialog content to ajax source, after which positioning was a problem. The below worked for me today.

```
$('#formdialog').dialog({autoOpen: false, modal: true, title:'Dialog Title',  
    position: {
    my: "center top", 
    at: "center top+50", 
    of: window
}});
```

Note that the '+50' is "50px down from the top" and works whether adding to the "my" or "at" line. Spaces not permitted. For example: "center top + 50" will not work.

See more info in documentation [option-position](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a simple solution and realized that my graph wasn't finished "drawing"
before opening the dialog so I enclosed the .dialog('open') command in a setTimeout function.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#pie-Admin-Summary-dialog').dialog('open');
}, 500);
```

You can play with the timing.  I opted for 1/2 second.