# jQuery UI dialog won't center properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jQuery pop-up dialog that I want to have a `max-width` on, and I want it centered.  I also want to re-use the same `div` for its content.  My issue is that if you set `width:auto` when opening the dialog, as you need to do for `max-width` to kick in, the dialog won't centre properly if you first pop-up some text that *doesn't* cause an overflow, and then pop-up some text that *does*:

http://jsfiddle.net/kxCuq/2/

As you can see, the second time round the pop-up is moved over to the right instead of horizontally centered.  Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: This looks like it may have your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220086/jquery-dialog-auto-resize-on-dynamic-content-and-maintain-center-position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that once you change the width of content, destroy and re-create it so that jQuery can re-calculate the width and the center.

Also, the `maxWidth` option specifies the *maximum width to which the dialog can be resized, in pixels*; so this option does not work the way you expect. Set the max width on the content. So we have:

```css
#dialog {
    max-width: 200px;
    display: none;
}
```

```js
$("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    width: "auto",
    close: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).dialog("destroy");
    }
});
```

[**Demo on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/kxCuq/7/)

Comment: Destroying the dialog on close each time worked perfectly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this a hard question. It really can be done easily by setting css attributes for 'ui-dialog' class.

Here's what to do:

After you set your html, add this jquery:

`$('.ui-dialog').css('position','relative');`

`$('.ui-dialog').css('margin','10px auto');`

If you want it to have fixed max-width for example for 400px, you can add this too:

`$('.ui-dialog').css('max-width','400px');`

If you want both box just be the same and exactly alike (first pop-up and second pop-up), you can add this to your css:

`.ui-dialog{
position:relative;
max-width:200px;
margin:10px auto 10px auto;
}`

Here's Live Demo Link:

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MFmCB/1/)

Answer (score 0):

`width:auto` appears to be the culprit.  Remove it and everything centers properly.

If you need to be setting the widths, there's a setter you can use to change width when you change content:  `$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "width", 500 );`

Comment: But then you don't get the `max-width` functionality - I only want the dialog to be as wide as it needs to be.