# How to position dialog box on the center of the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have JQuery dialog box and I have a problem to position the box on the center. Here is my code:

```
$.extend({ 
    alert: function (message, title) {
        $("<div></div>").dialog( {
            buttons: { "Ok": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
            close: function (event, ui) { $(this).remove(); },
            resizable: false,
            title: title,
            modal: true,
            width:'auto',
            .position({
                    my: "center",
                    at: "center",
                    of: window
            })
        }).html(message);
    }
});
```

And here is how I call my jquery dialog box:

```
$.alert('<div>My Dialog Box test.</div>', 'My File');
```

Here is my working example: `https://jsfiddle.net/dmilos89/wn1fy15f/1/`

Also I use jquery-ui-1.12.1 Jquery version. If anyone can help please let me know.

Comment: jquery ui dialog defaults to center: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default where are you getting it?

Comment: It on the center of the screen but stretch's from the center all the way to the right edge of the screen. I would like to put my box in the middle evenly stretch on the both sides of the screen. I'm not sure but maybe width:'auto' is causing this.

Comment: I just tested and if I set width to 800 for example my box is in the middle and everything looks good. If I change width to auto then my box is on the right side of the screen.

Comment: Maybe you could place your whole code in a fiddle?

Comment: My question is updated.

Comment: Are you including the jQuery UI css in your header?

Comment: Isn't possible to position it with css?

Comment: I have include in my header. I'm not sure if css can handle this.

Comment: setting the width to a fixed value fixed the issue in your jsfiddle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - Dialog auto-resize on dynamic content and maintain center position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220086/jquery-dialog-auto-resize-on-dynamic-content-and-maintain-center-position)

Answer (score 0):

which version of jquery used? if you used after 1.12 , u don't need to use position in dialog properties

Comment: I listed everything in my question above. Thank you.

Comment: so that you can take out position property, try it

Answer (score 0):

```
$.extend({ 
    alert: function (message, title) {
        $("<div></div>").dialog( {
            buttons: { "Ok": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
            close: function (event, ui) { $(this).remove(); },
            resizable: false,
            title: title,
            modal: true,
            width: '600px',
            position : {
                    my: "center",
                    at: "center",
                    of: window
            }
        }).html(message);
    }
});
```

You have an error where you are declaring the `position`.  Also when you declared `width:'auto'` you need to set that to a fixed width.

Comment: This will stretch the box to the right side of the screen. Still the same as I had before...

Comment: Try setting a fixed width.  Or removing width altogether.  I've never seen anyone set width to `auto` before.